# Distance of user's location from my current location

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2, Here is my list of users from API with latitude and longitude. i need to show the distance of users from my current location with google map API? How can i use the below geolocation code inside my ts file?

**jSon:**

```
data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Adil",
         "latitude":"21.560362",
         "longitude":"39.134023"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"John",
         "latitude":"22.560212",
         "longitude":"39.133765"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "name":"Muhammed",
         "latitude":"22.560212",
         "longitude":"39.133765"
      }
   ]
```

**ts file:**

```
export class AboutPage {

    public items: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http, public platform: Platform) {
        this.http = http;
        this.platform = platform;

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.http.get("PathToMyUsersApiFile").subscribe(data => {
                this.items = JSON.parse(data['_body']).data;
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        });

    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-item>
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>

<!-- distance from current location -->
        <p>{{item.distance}}</p>

    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Geolocation code:**

```
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

        var currentLocation = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
        var usersLocation = []; // Users location

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;         
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [origin1],
            destinations: usersLocation,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status !== 'OK') {
                alert('Error was: ' + status);
            } else {
                var results = response.rows[0].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    console.log(results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text);
                }
            }
        });

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: i don't know where i need to put the Geolocation code and how to get the {{item.distance}} value in my list.

Comment: How can i push the results[j].distance.text to this.items?

Comment: check the code below. When you mutate the array with an asynchronous call it will be updated in templated. Did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {

}

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.http.get("PathToMyUsersApiFile").subscribe(data => {
            this.items = JSON.parse(data['_body']).data;

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

    var currentLocation = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
    var usersLocation = []; // Users location

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService; 
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin1],
        destinations: usersLocation,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, (response, status) => {
        if (status !== 'OK') {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else {
            var results = response.rows[0].elements;
            this.zone.run(()=>{        
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                this.items[j].distance=results[j].distance.text
            }
            })
        }
    });

}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });
```

Points to note.

1. You havent set the origin in the code
2. notice the use of arrow function so that `this` is possible.(`()=>{}`)
3. There are many ways to refactor the code. like moving the logic to a `service` and combining the `Observable` and `Promise` with `flatMap`

Hope it helped

Comment: i tried the above code, i think the list is building before this loop. so the distance is not loading in the list

Comment: when i try: this.items[0].distance= 'my test';  inside the response, its not working. but its working outside.

Comment: did you change to arrow function?

Comment: do you get response from maps with distance?

Comment: I tried a similar example and it works. The ``DOM`` will be updated if value changes. You need to debug with browser console.

Comment: I have list item click function :- (click)="itemTapped($event, item), The list is updating with the distance values when i click on the item, by default its not loading distance values.

Comment: Still the result is same.

Comment: Here is my example : https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnt49yqmhiqxlkl/Ionic2RESTHttpExample-master.zip?dl=0